# Grails 2.3.9 - Error: ClassNotFoundException: grails.plugin.spock.test.GrailsSpecTestType

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, spock, grails-2.3

Whenever I enter the grails command: test-app I get this error:

```
Error executing script TestApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: grails.plugin.spock.test.GrailsSpecTestType (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

In my BuildConfig.groovy I have:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    ...
    plugins {
        ...
        test ":spock:0.7"
    }
}
```

I've tried replacing it with compile ":spock:0.7" . 
I've also tried cleaning the application and refreshing the dependencies but no luck.

Any ideas what it could be and how I could fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for Grails 2.2+ try this code in your BuildConfig:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
  repositories {
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    test "org.spockframework:spock-grails-support:0.7-groovy-2.0"
  }
  plugins {
    test(":spock:0.7") {
      exclude "spock-grails-support"
    }
  }
}
```

for more info just check out:
https://grails.org/plugin/spock